# Ubuntu based distro with slim storage footprint

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, ubuntu-mate, distro-recommendation, mass-storage

I am looking to install Linux on a new laptop I have, with only 64gb of storage.

I am curious if there are any sources that compare the base install size of various distros.

I am not looking to go off the beaten path, so I am really only considering maybe Lubuntu, Xubuntu, or Ubuntu Mate. I might consider Ubuntu 18.04 with minimal install, but I only have 4gb ram as well, so I rather avoid gnome.

Is there any hard data (besides recommended storage size) that I can look into?

Comment: FIY - from my experience Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS amd64 uses about 6 Gb of storage. Do not know about GNOME and Xfce.

Comment: Hard data would not be very useful anyway.  I've Lubuntu 16.04 installed (with MATE & XFCE also) running on a machine with 40gb disk (1.5gb ram). All three DEsktops are good and I select at login. This however is because of how I use it.   64gb is fine for all you mention, however if you start loading lots of software, lots of data and hope to release-upgrade to next version (which needs lots of space) that's when any can run into problems.  With my t43 thinkpad I don't expect to be able to release-upgrade (no free space) though it may have been more possible had I not loaded the 3DE's on it..

Comment: My point was 64gb storage & 4gb ram is great for many many roles, but it'll depend on how you use it.  I like working on 32gb minimals (32 for /; 32 for /home [*ignoring swap*]), but I also can split a 80gb disk into dual boot without issues (but release-upgrade will be near impossible with use; so re-install).   If you like adding software (and don't remove it), your system with grow :)

Comment: 64Gb is more than enough to do ANYTHING with any Ubuntu version.  So is 4Gb in RAM. @N0rbert even less ;-)  Even installing lots of software you will only get close to 25Gb. It is the user data you need to manage: you will have a hard time if you start downloading movies or music collections and want to keep them on the system.  Videos will be watch and delete at some point. I do not see any reason why a normal Ubuntu install would not work.

Comment: All these comments are moot. It is OBVIOUS that user data takes up space. The whole point is to have the smallest OS possible base, to make room for as much user data as possible......seriously.....pro tip......movies take space. Thanks for the insight! :P

Comment: You could simply compare the size of the ISO files to get a rough idea although Installed sizes will be larger I think you'll find the ISO's with the smallest size produce the smallest installed size Lubuntu and Xubuntu are just plain tiny compared to some of the alternatives. Regardless of which you choose you'll have plenty of running room.